# How to transform L2-norm constraint into SOCP

Tags: convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I was wondering if you could help with the idea of how the following problem can be converted into a standard SOCP.

$\underset{\{\mathbf{W}_{1}\}}{\text{min}} \ \| \mathbf{w}_{1} \| ^{2}_{2}\\
\text{s.t} \ \ \ \mathbf{h}^{T}\boldsymbol{\Pi }\mathbf{w}_{1} +\delta \| \boldsymbol{\Pi} \mathbf{w}_{1} \| _{2} =0 \notag\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathbf{h}^{T}\mathbf{w}_{1} +\delta \| \mathbf{w}_{1} \| \geq \sqrt{\Gamma w_{0}} \notag\\
 \notag\\
 \notag$

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: the problem is not convex, so you cannot do such a conversion

Comment: Thank you LinAlg. Is there a way of converting the problem to Convex?

Comment: I'm afraid not, no.